# I need to make an international wire transfer in 2-3 days -- how can I do that?

Tags: united-states, international-transfer, wire-transfer, swift

I need to make a wire transfer (from the USA) to an international bank in the next 3 business days. They specifically ask for an MT 103 receipt, so I don't think alternatives to SWIFT will work.

I checked my bank's website and it says international wire transfers can take up to 10 days. Is there some way I can speed up the transfer? Is there a bank or company that's known to make international wire transfers faster?

Comment: If the recipient is asking for the money in a hurry then they ought to be able to tell you a way to get the money to them that meets their criteria. It would be remiss of me not to ask (because scam artists often rely on a sense of urgency to get around people's natural defences) - are you 100% sure that the requested transfer is legitimate and not a scam?

Comment: @Vicky Yes, it's legit. They gave me ample time, but I procrastinated too much. So, this was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the amount of time to complete a SWIFT wire transfer is rarely up to the sending bank. If you're transferring from a large bank directly connected to the SWIFT network (no intermediaries on the sending side), then it gets to the destination when it gets there. Banks usually send wires out on a daily basis, with cut-off somewhere in the afternoon (Eastern time).

The banks say it can take *up to* 10 days precisely because there's little they can do about the rest of the system. Usually it takes less, but you can never know.